# Multiple values column change breaks form in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath, form, sorting, multiple-values

I need to be able to sort a lookup column.  I made this possible by unchecking the "allow multiple values" option in list settings, however now I cannot edit existing entries in the list.  When I try to edit I get this error message "There has been an error while loading the form because the fields in the form and SharePoint list do not match. Contact the list owner to update the form."  (I am the list owner) When I open the form in InfoPath I get this prompt: "One or more fields in the SharePoint list have changed.  Do you want InfoPath to update the set of available fields?  You may need to add or modify your form view to add or remove the updated fields."  I click "yes."  Then I try to publish the form and get this error message "The publish operation cannot be completed.  It cannot be determined if the form template was successfully published.  Try publishing the form template again, or change the list settings to use the default SharePoint form.  Details: The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
"

The form is not published.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Do your InfoPath form controls for the lookup columns still exist as "multiple-selection" boxes instead of "list" boxes? This is what the part of the error that says "You may need to add or modify your form view to add or remove the updated fields" refers to.

Comment: Thank you @user11457, this turned into a much larger issue as I can't remove the check from "multiple values" as some of the listing do have multiple values and that deletes all but one value.  How do I close a question here?  Or select aqn answer?

Comment: You can select an answer by hitting the checkmark under the vote buttons. I don't know any way of closing a question.

Comment: I have no checkmark under the vote option.  I see no vote buttons.